How to completely and permanently remove a system app from Android?
I'm using Android 14 with KernelSU root access and TWRP recovery on a OnePlus 12 running OxygenOS 14.
What I've Tried:

I can see /product/app/YouTube/YouTube.apk using Termux or
Root Explorer when the system is booted, but I can’t delete it
because it's read-only and mounting doesn't seem to work.
TWRP doesn’t show the /product/app/YouTube folder, so I can't access
it through recovery.
Tried uninstalling YouTube using Lucky Patcher, but it reappears
after reboot.

Question:
How can I permanently delete the YouTube app and prevent it from returning after each reboot? I'm not looking to just disable it; I want to completely remove it from the system.

As the system partition can't be remounted you can not delete the Youtube apk fro your system partition. I am not an expert to this but may be there is a way to add an filesystem overlay that "deletes" or renames it https://github.com/HuskyDG/magic_overlayfs

@Robert Thanks for the suggestion, but I've already tried looking into magic_overlayfs, and unfortunately, it hasn't worked for me. The last proper release was over a year ago, and it seems like the project might be abandoned.

the whole KernelSU instructions looks like a copy paste of Magisk instructions. maybe try Magisk instead?

@alecxs After browsing the issues section of the module, it seems it's not working with Magisk 27 either.

try to create super partition (not sure that is possible on A14)

@alecxs I've decompressed the ROM, but I couldn't find a super.img file. This leads me to believe that there's likely no super partition on OxygenOS 14

on TWRP adb shell: 'find /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name'

@alecxs I found  /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/super what should I do now?

'adb pull /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/super' it will take a while. look for super file on PC and try to unpack system from it

@alecxs, after numerous attempts, I successfully unpacked the super file and discovered the YouTube folder within /my_heytap_a.img/app. It was also present in the my_heytap.img extracted from the ROM

so maybe now you discovered the correct path try again to hide with overlay?

@alecxs Unfortunately, the module isn't working for me
